# How to make zk boderlayout to fit any resolution screen

Tags: zk, border-layout, zul

```
 <window  height="300px">
    <borderlayout >

        <north height="60px" ></north>

        <west width="200px" ></west>

        <center></center>

        <east width="200px" ></east>

        <south height="40px"></south>

    </borderlayout>
</window>
```

Currently i have to set the `window` `height` to a `pixel` value for this to work properly..

So if my screen resolution height is `300px` then it will cover the complete screen.

But will not fill up the complete screen for different resolutions...

How to make this hardcoded value to be dynamic based to user screen resolution ?

I cannot remove `window` tag.

[zkfiddle example](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/t11t2o/1-Another-new-ZK-fiddle)

Comment: use height="somthing%"

Comment: It wont work... you can try it on zkfiddle example i have provided

Comment: Only solution i found is to set height in javascript and then fire a onresize event....

Comment: `<window height="100%">` fills up the full height

Comment: yep it worked now ...wondering why it did not worked for me before

Comment: It works in zkfiddle but not in sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<window  height="100%">
```

should do the trick.
Maybe [Media Queries](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/November/How_to_Apply_Responsive_Design#ZK.27s_Support_to_Responsive_Design) could be interesting for you too.